# Getting two different results in a SQL SELECT with the same variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get two different result sets with a `SELECT` using an `INNER JOIN` on different tables.

Let me show you what I got so far:

```
select 
    refugo.id, 
    cadastro_motivos.motivo as defeito, 
    cadastro_motivos.motivo as causa, 
    refugo.op_producao, 
    refugo.quantidade, 
    maquina.nome,
    to_char(refugo.data, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')
from 
    refugo 
inner join 
    cadastro_motivos on refugo.id_motivo = cadastro_motivos.id
inner join 
    maquina on maquina.id = refugo.id_maquina
order by 
    refugo.id asc
```

I've been trying to use an alias for the column `cadastro_motivos.motivo`, but I don't have no clue how to connect with the inner join that I use.

The column `refugo.id_motivo` is the one I need to use for make a connection. I have a second column `refugo.id_motivo2` that I need to refer to the column `cadastro_motivos.id`.

This is a valid question? I am lost in my thoughts here... Any advice will be great!

Comment: Please do not use mark up code (`**`) in you code.... now it's an invalid SQL statement.

Comment: Where is this imaginary column `refugo.id_motivo2` ?

Comment: When you can make your problem more clear using example data, please do so!

Comment: I don't no how to use the column without enter in conflict with the **refugo.id_motivo** . Basically this is where I'm struggling now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the same table `cadasto_motivo` twice. You'll need to use aliases (`m1` and `m2` below) to differentiate the columns of them.

For example:

```
select 
    refugo.id, 
    m1.motivo as defeito, -- retrieving "motivo" from 1st one
    m2.motivo as causa, -- retrieving "motivo" from 2nd one
    refugo.op_producao, 
    refugo.quantidade, 
    maquina.nome,
    to_char(refugo.data, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')
from 
    refugo 
inner join -- joining first time as "m1"
    cadastro_motivos m1 on refugo.id_motivo = m1.id
inner join -- joining second time as "m2"
    cadastro_motivos m2 on refugo.id_motivo2 = m2.id
inner join 
    maquina on maquina.id = refugo.id_maquina
order by 
    refugo.id asc
```